# How can I capture the git branch name in Azure DevOps release name?

Tags: git, github, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to implement CI/CD for our database changes. I'm trying to capture the git branch name in the Azure DevOps pipeline release name.

[image]

I've tried using `System.PullRequest.SourceBranch` & `Build.PullRequest.TargetBranchName` but these haven't worked.

`Build.SourceBranch` only displays the base branch `develop`, so that isn't going to work. `Build.SourceVersionMessage` does work if I manually add a note. I can't remember at what step, I think when I confirm the merge of the PR branch. But that's another manual step that I really don't want.

So I'm just wanting the name of the branch that is named based on the task number that we create, steps we take:

1. I create a new branch with the task number and publish
2. I add the SQL file that is to be deployed to GitHub and commit the change
3. I create a pull request and merge
4. This automatically kicks off the pipeline
5. I delete the branch that was created

Right now we only build off the base branch, `develop`. Something about branch protection and consolidation. I don't think our git process is going to change.

Comment: Source branch only represents the branch in question from the context of the PR. After the PR is merged, from the POV of `develop`, source branch doesn't exist anymore. Since you are running the pipeline against `develop` after the merge is done, I think the info you want is: "What was the name of the last branch that was merged into `develop`?" That information isn't captured by Git, unless it's written into a commit message somewhere. You would have to parse out the PR number and go look up that PR to see what the branch name was.

Comment: By the way, #5 usually happens as part of #3, since the branch has no meaning after it's merged, except for the branch *name*. The fact that the branch is hanging around, gives you the opportunity to look at the commit ID that was last merged into `develop` (if not rewritten), and then go find a branch name that is pointing to that commit ID, and maybe you'll get lucky that it's the only one, and if so you could use its branch name to get what you want. This will probably work most of the time, but it assumes your devs won't delete the branch when completing the PR, which isn't very robust...

Comment: After PR completion, if you're sitting on `develop` and `HEAD` is a merge commit, and you're fairly certain the branch hasn't been deleted yet, then something like this might work (in bash) for listing the branch name: `git ls-remote | grep $(git rev-parse HEAD^2)`

Comment: @TTT I'm getting close, I was able to capture 'Merge pull request #34 from myrepo/test4' from ```Build.SourceVersionMessage``` when it is set in the .yml. 
 ```test4``` would be the branch name I created for the PR! Now I'm getting "The build number format string" warning because of special characters. Do you know how to work with strings outputted from tokens/variables in yaml? I'm thinking of just replacing all special characters, or maybe even truncating at the /

Comment: @TTT I got something that will work, I edited the yml setting ```name: $(Build.SourceVersionMessage)``` and then passing ``$(Build.Buildnumber)``` in the Release name format under Options>General in the release. However, it only works when the pipeline is kicked off automatically after the merge. If I manually kick off the pipeline the BuildNumber is null. >:-| FYI I had to do some additional string formatting in the yml as the string contained a '/' etc. at least there was a replace function available yesh...